# get medium size instead of full

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am struggling to get the medium Size for an URL to an Image in Wordpress. My working source looks like this:

```
<div class="entry-thumbnail coverback" style="background-image: url(<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() ); ?>); ">
```

but that calls for the full image and by that my Page explodes to 9-10 MB per load as the uploaded full images are a bit bigger.

So I have Tried so far without success:

```
<div class="entry-thumbnail coverback" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $image_attr = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'medium');  ?>); ">
```

and

```
<div class="entry-thumbnail coverback" style="background-image: url(<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image ( int $attachment_id, string|array $size = 'medium', bool $icon = false, string|array $attr = '' );  ?>); ">
```

and

```
<div class="entry-thumbnail coverback" style="background-image: url(<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( get_the_ID(), array('medium') );  ?>); ">
```

but not one of them worked, what am I doing wrong here? I have tried to use the WP Codex and stuff, but.. that mostly confused me more than it helped :(

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [wp_get_attachment_image_src docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/), the function returns an array.  The first element in the array is the src url, so you need to modify your code as follows:

```
<?php 
// Load the attachment attributes
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'medium');  
// IF it's an array, and the url (index 0) is set, then assign it
$image = (isset($image[0])) ? $image[0] : ''; 
?>
<div class="entry-thumbnail coverback" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $image; ?>); ">
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try this as soon as i have again access to the site. This is by FAR different from what I had expected!!!

Comment: AWESOME! From 9-10MB to under 1MB. Thank you very much!